# How to I rosbag/record a loosless compressed images

Tags: ros, rosbag, image, image-transport, compressed

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I like to record raw images using rosbag.

```
rosbag record /front_camera/image_raw
```

Works perfect  and I can view the images with

```
rosbag play my_bag.bag &
rosrun image_view image_view /front_camera/image_raw
```

But the bag files becomes get big very fast

My question is now is there a way to record images loosless compressed?
Currently I see the following topics

```
/front_camera/image_raw
/front_camera/image_raw/compressed
/front_camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/front_camera/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/front_camera/image_raw/compressedDepth
/front_camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/front_camera/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/front_camera/image_raw/theora
/front_camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/front_camera/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
```

I tried recording the  /front_camera/image_raw/compressed or  /front_camera/image_raw/theora butI was not able to view the recorded images using image_view.

Thanks
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129266/how-to-i-rosbag/record-a-loosless-compressed-images/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2014-02-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Record compressed stream via:

```
$ rosbag record /front_camera/image_raw/compressed
```

Play back recording with:

```
$ rosbag play <bagfile>
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/front_camera/image_raw compressed
```

note the space between the raw topic and the transport type in image_view.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-03-05**:
Keep in mind that by default, compressed_image_transport uses JPEG, which is lossy. You can use dynamic_reconfigure to switch it to PNG.

**Comment by [Tinrik](https://answers.ros.org/users/13131/tinrik/) on 2014-07-07**:
I have a node that processes data from a sensor_msgs/Image topic, and I don't want to modify the code. Can I apply what you just said: record a bag file with compressed images, and then and somehow convert from compressed image to "raw" image when I read directly from the bag?